# Discord bot replies multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to make my first discord bot that executes a command but the problem is that if a user dms !command to the bot with a link, the bot replies multiple times because the command executes multiple times.

```
client.on('message', msg1 => {
  if (msg1.content.startsWith("!command")) {
    var splitMessage = msg1.content.split(" ");
    if (splitMessage[1] != undefined) {
      var url = splitMessage[1];
      if (url.includes("google.com")) {
        var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999999) + 1);
        var cmd = 'wkhtmltopdf ' + url + ' ' + x + '.pdf';

        var options = {
          encoding: 'utf8'
        }

        var filename = x + '.pdf';
        console.log(execSync(cmd, options));
        msg1.reply({ files: [filename] });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bot reply a message multiple times, because it reply it's message itself.

You need detect the message which comes from bot, and ignore it.

`message.author.bot` return a boolean value, if it is `true`, this mean the message comes form a bot instead of human.

You could look my code as follow:

```
client.on('message', msg1 => {
  // detect bot message
  if (msg1.author.bot) {
    // do nothing
    console.log('Ignoring bot message!');
    return;
  }
  if (msg1.content.startsWith("!command")) {
    var splitMessage = msg1.content.split(" ");
    if (splitMessage[1] != undefined) {
      var url = splitMessage[1];
      if (url.includes("google.com")) {
        var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999999) + 1);
        var cmd = 'wkhtmltopdf ' + url + ' ' + x + '.pdf';

        var options = {
          encoding: 'utf8'
        }

        var filename = x + '.pdf';
        console.log(execSync(cmd, options));
        msg1.reply({ files: [filename] });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons a discord bot would reply multiple times to a message, lets go through each one and see which on is the cause.

#### The bot is replying to its own reply, getting stuck in an infinite loop

Discord.js calls the on('message') callback for all messages received, even if the bot is the author of the message. This could result in the bot replying to its own messages and triggering an infinite loop

We can simply avoid this by ignoring all messages that are coming from our bot.

```
if(msg.author == client.user) return;
```

#### The bot is replying to another bots message, getting stuck in an infinite conversation

Similar to the previous case the, we might want our bot to ignore messages coming from other bots in the same server. Luckily discord.js has a flag for whether messages come from bots or regular user.

We can simply avoid this by ignoring all messages that are coming from all bots.

```
if(msg.author.bot) return;
```

A quick look through your code shows that the bot is replying to messages that start with '!command' and that its reply doesn't contain '!command' therefor it shouldn't reply to itself, even without the return suggested above.

#### So what could cause a bot to reply to the same message multiple times other than an issue with the code?

Well, there is a chance that your bot is behaving perfectly and only replying once but that there are multiple instances of your bot running. Each instance of the bot is treated as its own and therefor replies to the message on its own, ignoring what the other instance is doing.